# Parse formatted datetime expression and assign numbers to variables

Tags: php, web-services, refactoring, substr

I have this string from eBay Web-Service.

> // 2Days  23Hours 37Minutes 50Seconds
> $string = P2DT23H37M50S

I was using the following code to extract and time and date:

> $daysLeft = substr($string, 1, 1) . " Days";
> $hoursLeft = substr($string, 4, 2) . " Hours";
> $minutesLeft = substr($string, 7, 2) . " Minutes";
> $secondsLeft = substr($string, 10, 2) . " Seconds";

But the problem is, When the hours, minutes and dates are only 1 Digit, the strings gets all messed up, I had it working initially, but I'm kind of stuck to find a simple way to do it, I was going to write it in a bunch of If statements, but really want a more simple way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using [sscanf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php) (the opposite of sprintf)?

```
list($daysLeft, $hoursLeft, $minutesLeft, $secondsLeft) = sscanf($string, "P%dDT%dH%dM%DS ");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you now that all fields always is there, just preg_split the string on non-numbers:

```
$fields = preg_split('[^0-9]+', $string);
$daysLeft = $fields[1] . " Days";
$hoursLeft = $fields[2] . " Hours";
$minutesLeft = $fields[3] . " Minutes";
$secondsLeft = $fields[4] . " Seconds";
```